# Returning distinct values of nested objects with Spring Data from CosmosDB

Tags: spring-data, azure-cosmosdb

I've seen very basic CRUD operations supported by the Azure CosmosDB Spring Data project (see https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/master/sdk/cosmos/azure-spring-data-cosmos-core), but no  examples of advanced usage.

Given documents like this:

```
{
  "someKey": "someValue",
  "child": {
     "someArray": ["one", "two"]
  }
}
```

Is there a way to get the distinct values of `child.someArray`? This is possible via the SQL Api and AsyncDocumentClient, but looking at the code, I suspect this is currently impossible to do via the Spring Data API. It also does not seem possible to specify custom queries using an annotation on a repository class method.
I tried something like this (simplified example), to no avail:

```
class Document{ Child child; }
class Child { String[] someArray; }

MyRepository {
  Root findDistinctChildSomeArray();
  String[] findDistinctChildSomeArray();
}
```